# Apply top-down transformation "bird's eye" view in opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying to get a bird's eye view for a captured image from a car. The pictures are mainly a road that I need later to process to detect lane lines. I'm stuck in finding the right dest and src points for my images. Any help is highly appreciated!

Here is a sample of the picture that my camera took. The dimension is 320x240.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a great explanation of "bird's eye view" transformation ib one of the best OpenCV books: "Learning opencv. Computer vision with the opencv library." by Gary Bradski, Adrian Kaehler.

In your case you may use road corners as source points (which give you a road trapezoid). And corners of desired output as destination points (rectangular). Assume to keep same order of points, e.g. TL-TR-BR-BL.

With such order and desired output size `200x500` (try to save road's proportions) destination points will be: `(0, 0), (200, 0), (200, 500), (0, 500)`.

Comment: My issue was with the order of the points, I will give it a try and see if it works!

Comment: Any order will apply, just remain same order in src and dst points.